# Where are these extra references coming from?

Tags: python, reference-counting

I thought i was finally getting the hang of reference-counting in python, until i came up with the below sample code (tested at [repl.it](http://repl.it)). Its result raised 3 questions:

1. <s>Why do `This` and `That` start off with 2 references?</s>
2. The proxy-referenced `this` object in `that.objects` should die when `this` is killed; yet the method remains. Why is that?
3. After deleting `that`, without running `gc.collect()`, the reference to `that` appears to have been collected; but the weak-proxied reference to `this`'s `foo` method isn't. Why is that?

Thanks in advance.

```
import sys, weakref, gc

def printf():
    print 'Actual   -> ', "This:", sys.getrefcount(This), ' ', 'That:', sys.getrefcount(That), '\n'

class This():
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = [ self.foo ]
    def foo(self):
        pass

class That():
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.objects = [ weakref.proxy(kw['obj']).foo ]
        #self.objects = [ kw['obj'] ]
    def bar(self):
        pass


print '### Before ###'
print 'Expected -> ', "This: 1", ' ', 'That: 1'
printf()

this = This(); that = That(**{'obj': this})

print '### Start Runtime ###'
print 'Expected -> ', "This: 3", ' ', 'That: 2'
printf()

del this
gc.collect()

print '### Important Event ###'
print 'Expected -> ', "This: 1", ' ', 'That: 2'
printf()

del that

print '### Secondary Event ###'
print 'Expected -> ', "This: 1", ' ', 'That: 1'
printf()
```

Comment: You can use [`gc.get_referrers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) to see what's referring to a particular object (for your first question).

Comment: The minimum count you'll ever see from `sys.getrefcount` is always 2, because passing an object to the `sys.getrefcount` function requires an extra reference.

Comment: @Blckknght except for something like `sys.getrefcount(object())`

Comment: @Blckknght: Thanks. But was it too much to throw a `-1` in there? Just sayin...